# Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'layout'

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cosmicmind

```
private func prepareContainerView() {
    containerView = UIView()
    view.layout(containerView).edges(top: 100, left: 20, right: 20)
    //The above line is showing error
}
```

This is from a sample project of CosmicMind Material. I cant seem to run the project as the error is insisting. Please help

Comment: Hey! What version of Material are you using? And if the `development` branch, when was the last time you updated?

Comment: Hello, i install via pod (pod 'Material', '~> 1.0').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use version 1.42.9 at least :) All the best!